# Pyasn1 BER encoding with carriage return \r\n

Tags: python, asn.1

I'm handling BER encoded Call Data Records (CDR). from GPRS Tunneling protocol. In which I got one field's value with `'\r\n'` in it.

`'\xa0\x06\x80\x04\r\n\xc4\x086'`   -- This is the encoded string or `bytearray` which causing the issue. It has all the TLV information required for the tag **a0**, and its length is **06**. There is an inner tag **80** and its length is **04**. But if we take the output in the following way it prints like this.

The inner tag **80**'s value causing the issue. Its length is **04** but when we decode it with `pyasn1` the length became **05** since it counts `\r` and `\n` separately. I think the encoder which encodes this data assumes that `\r\n` is a single element. But while decoding this using pyasn1 it throwing an error due to this missing length on the TLV representation of encoded value.

```
map(ord, '\xa0\x06\x80\x04\r\n\xc4\x086')
[160, 6, 128, 4, 13, 10, 196, 8, 54]
```

We are using implicit tag numbers.

Is there any way to solve this using pyasn1's ber decoder and encoder.

Thanks and Regards,

Haridas N.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with pyasn1, but I'd suggest focusing on the data coming in, as that to me suggests that there's something treating what should be a binary set of bytes as text...

If the inner tag is really of len 4 then has a \n been replaced by a \r\n?

Comment: The In place replacement hack won't work. I want to know, is this a normal behavior in the asn1 data or specially for pyasn1 ?

Comment: I didn't find an another solution yet... So for the time being I'm go ahead with the replacement option. Thank you.

Comment: No, it's certainly not a normal thing to have to do with asn1 data!